# Operator >= cannot be applied to operands of type string and datetime

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, asp.net-web-api2

The user enters two parameters in the url which are the start date and end date and they are entered in the format `yyyyMMddhhmm` as a string. I'm attempting to take these strings and turn them into dates so I can query my database.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Detail))]
public IHttpActionResult GetDetail(string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
    DateTime StartDateTime;
    DateTime EndDateTime;

    StartDateTime = new DateTime();
    EndDateTime = new DateTime();

    StartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);
    EndDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);

    var detail = from a in db.Details where (a.callDate >= StartDateTime && a.callDate <= EndDateTime) select a;

    var Response = new DetailResponse() { status = true, calls = detail };
    return Ok(response);
}
```

However I get the error that >= can't be used in datetime and strings.

**EDIT:**
For the sake of one of the answer I'm including a model class I'm using to display the data.

**DetailResponse.cs**

```
public class DetailResponse
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public string statusMessage { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Detail> calls { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what type is a.callDate?

Comment: Ah, it is a string in my sql database.

Comment: You can declare and assign your `DateTime`s in one statement: `DateTime StartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);`

Comment: Then you should parse that as datetime also

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you can't compare two different types. I realise that by now there are plenty of answers already but what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably this is happening, because `callDate` is a string. So you can't compare a string with a datetime. The solution to this problem is to have the same type. That being said I would convert `a.callDate` to a `DateTime`.

However, I think that it would be better you change the data type of `callDate` in the database level. Undoubtedly, this is a personal opinion. So you don't have to follow it. Doing so your code will not need any change.

Now, in terms of code the solution I suggested above is the following:

```
var allDetails = db.Details.AsEnumerable();
var details = from detail in details
              let callDate = DateTime.ParseExact(detail.callDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null)
              where callDate >= StartDateTime 
              && callDate <= EndDateTime
              select detail;
```

**Update**

As we concluded in comments, we had to call the `AsEnumerable`, in order the above query to work. Why is this needed?

Borrowing Jon Skeet's words from [Reimplementing Linq to Objects: Part 36 – AsEnumerable](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable/)

> Now it’s not entirely uncommon to want to perform some aspects of the
>   query in the database, and then a bit more manipulation in .NET –
>   particularly if there are aspects you basically can’t implement in
>   LINQ to SQL (or whatever provider you’re using). For example, you may
>   want to build a particular in-memory representation which isn’t really
>   amenable to the provider’s model.

The `DateTime.ParseExact` cannot be translated properly in a database method.

Comment: Well I'm working with an api and they want the repsonse back to be a string but it seems I need to have it as a datetime if I want to compare what the user types in the url.

Comment: It seems like it should work but I'm getting an outrageous amount of errors.
https://imgur.com/3lkLgXP

Comment: hmm...I got it...Please try the update and let me know. Thanks

Comment: That actually interferes with my model (my fault I never posted it). Do you recommend I change the model? I updated my question to show it. When implementing your answer `detail` has an error that it cant convert IEnumerable to IQueryable

Comment: Not a problem at all. Yes, you have also to change your model. The type of `calls` should be changed to `IEnumerable<Detail>`.

Comment: Ok so, running the query and the program stops, with an error highlighting the `let callDate = DateTime.ParseExact(a.callDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null)`: `When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the Datetime object.`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error on that line. It seems at this point it might be easier to just convert the type to datetime in the database then back to string before I output it.

Comment: Making the change in the db level would make your code far more efficient than the code solution I have in my answer. If you have the time, please check the link I referred to above in my answer, in order you understand what `AsEnumerable` actually does.

Comment: Yeah of course, I'm going to read that soon. Thanks for all of the assistance, it differently helped me realize what the best route was and it opened me up to a method that I didn't realize was possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is failing because the date in your database is of type string, try doing like this:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Detail))]
public IHttpActionResult GetDetail(string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
    DateTime StartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);
    DateTime EndDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);

    var detail = from a in db.Details where (DateTime.ParseExact(a.callDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null) >= StartDateTime && 
                    DateTime.ParseExact(a.callDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null) <= EndDateTime) select a;
}
```

However you are probably best off chaning the type of your `callDate` to a date instead of a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

What does your schema look like? is `callDate` a string? you may need to convert `callDate` to a `DateTime` before you can do the comparison.

```
var detail = from a in db.Details where (Convert.ToDateTime(a.callDate) >= StartDateTime &&  Convert.ToDateTime(a.callDate) <= EndDateTime) select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, you can't compare a string to a DateTime, however, given that the date format is

> yyyyMMddhhmm

(ie. year month day hour minute) where the values are all numeric and go from least varying -> most varying you will be safe doing a string comparison:

```
var detail = from a in db.Details where (a.callDate >= StartDate && a.callDate <= EndDate) select a;
```

This is because "201601010101" is less than "201612312359" when comparing strings (in the same way that "a" is less than "b").

This will save you converting the data to `DateTime`.

Having said that, by doing the conversion you are validating the data and can show an error if it's not in the right format.